# Splash Animation stop due to intent

Tags: android, animation, android-intent

This is a splash screen where a twitter like animation. I want to start a new activity after the animation is finish. 
I try to call activity inside

```
private void onLoadingDataEnded(){

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Intent i=new Intent(this,Frn_Activity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

But when i am calling it like this animation is not working.
When I call it after `splashAnDisappear` activity stop

```
mSplashView.splashAndDisappear(new ISplashListener(){

});
Intent i=new Intent(this,Frnt_mapActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
```

SplashActivity.java

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

  private static final String TAG = "SplashActivity";
  private static final boolean DO_XML = false;

  private ViewGroup mMainView;
  private SplashView mSplashView;
  private View mContentView;
  private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // change the DO_XML variable to switch between code and xml
    if(DO_XML==true){
      // inflate the view from XML and then get a reference to it

    } else {
      Log.d("Main","end now");
      // create the main view and it will handle the rest
      mMainView = new MainView(getApplicationContext());
      mSplashView = ((MainView) mMainView).getSplashView();
      setContentView(mMainView);
    }

    // pretend like we are loading data
    startLoadingData();
  }

  private void startLoadingData(){
    // finish "loading data" in a random time between 1 and 3 seconds
    Random random = new Random();
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
      @Override
      public void run(){
        onLoadingDataEnded();


      }
    }, 1000 + random.nextInt(2000));

  }

  private void onLoadingDataEnded(){

    // now that our data is loaded we can initialize the content view
    // add the content view to the background
    Context context = getApplicationContext();



    // add the content view to the background

    mSplashView.splashAndDisappear(new ISplashListener(){
      @Override
      public void onStart(){
        // log the animation start event
        if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){
          Log.d(TAG, "splash started");
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onUpdate(float completionFraction){
        // log animation update events
        if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){
          Log.d(TAG, "splash at " + String.format("%.2f", (completionFraction * 100)) + "%");
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onEnd(){
        // log the animation end event
        if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){
          Log.d(TAG, "splash ended");
        }
        // free the view so that it turns into garbage
        mSplashView = null;

        if(!DO_XML){
          // if inflating from code we will also have to free the reference in MainView as well
          // otherwise we will leak the View, this could be done better but so far it will suffice
          ((MainView) mMainView).unsetSplashView();

        }

      }


    });

  }
}
```

**So, My QUESTION is where do I start intent so that both animation and activity start and end properly.**
One more thing what can I use other than Intent to start the activity.
**EDIT** what can I use instead of intent because it is not working.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to call it in `onEnd()`? Also, you are in an Activity so you should use that Context instead of application context

Comment: I'm not an expert but I would say you would call it in your splashandDisappear methods onEnd(). Since that is when your splash would start to fade away. Or in the onUpdate() method

Comment: when I add  Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Frnt_mapActivity.class);
        startActivity(i); inside onEnd() animation work but activity is not starting

Comment: other than intent what can I use